# Why do I get a UnauthorizedAccessException when reading files from a network share?

Tags: c#, asp.net, directory

With this code:

```
DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo("\\s01\sharedfolder\folder");
FileInfo[] files = info.GetFiles().OrderBy(p => p.CreationTime).ToArray();
```

I get a `System.UnauthorizedAccessException`:

> Access to the path '\s01sharedfolder\folder' is denied.
>
> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '\s01\sharedfolder\folder' is denied.

On 's01' I have given `Everyone` full control to the `sharedfolder`. I also have set the owner of that shared folder to `everyone`.

The identity of the application pool of the .net app is set to `LocalSystem` and I have also tried to use the local administrator as the identity.

No matter what I try, I keep getting this exception. What do I need to do to fix this?

EDIT:
I have also tried to create a symbolic link, but this gave the same exception

Comment: `Everyone` is a misleading permission in windows. Your application don't have access to that particular folder.

Comment: What/who else can I try then? I now run my app under LocalSystem

Comment: Check this out. https://blog.varonis.com/the-difference-between-everyone-and-authenticated-users/

Comment: Do you mean \\s01?  Have you tried "\\\\s01\\sharedfolder\folder" or @"\\s01\sharedfolder\folder" - otherwise you are not setting path correctly - you are not escaping your folder separator

Comment: @Prajwal I have set the identity to `LocalService`, but with no success

Comment: @Andez The path is stored in the database and used as a variable in the code. In the exception I see that the correct path is used because when I copy the path and paste it on the server, it opens the folder.

Comment: LocalSystem will only be valid on your local machine.  If the share is on another computer then you will get this exception.  It might be worth setting up a dedicated account for your site to run under (IIS Pool) and granting the required permissions to resources on the network (ala your file share and database if using Windows Authentication) and local to your site (ala local file system).  Granted when running as System you get admin rights to that local machine only I think.

Comment: @Andez I have created the same account twice: one on both servers. Then I use this account as the identity for the application pool and now I can read the network share. Could you post an answer so I can mark this question as answered?

Comment: Are both machines on a domain?  Not too sure if that would work to be honest.  But I will put my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LocalSystem will only be valid on your local machine. If the share is on another computer then you will get this exception.

It might be worth setting up a dedicated account for your site to run under (IIS Pool) and granting the required permissions to resources on the network (ala your file share and database if using Windows Authentication) and local to your site (ala local file system).

Granted when running as System you get admin rights to that local machine only (I think).

Answer (score 0):

It might be the expected behavior for using File.OpenRead rather than a permission issue. File.OpenRead tries to open a file with that name in the local machine. Most of the time, the files are in the server, not in the local (client) machines. Therefore, it fails no matter what permissions are assigned to the folder. Try InputStream instead. Example:

```
String fileToUpload = FileUpload2.PostedFile.FileName;
long contentLength = FileUpload2.PostedFile.InputStream.Length;

byte[] buffer = new byte[contentLength];

FileUpload2.PostedFile.InputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
FileUpload2.PostedFile.InputStream.Read(buffer, 0, Convert.ToInt32(contentLength));

Stream stream = new MemoryStream(buffer);
```

Source: [System.UnauthorizedAccessException occurred in mscorlib.dll](https://port135.com/2019/07/25/system-unauthorizedaccessexception-occurred-mscorlib-dll/)